# Intuition behind Residual Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks

ResNet architecture states that instead of learning $H(x)$ function , it learns $f(x)$ which equals $f(x) = H(x) - x$ , my intuition was that instead of learning the function all at once , we just learn the difference between the previous block and the next block. but then I read that the network will try to get $f(x)$ to zero! and now I'm confused again, what's the point of doing that as this means we aren't learning anything?

Comment: "but then I read that the network will try to get $f(x)$ to zero!" - do you have any sources that claim this?

Comment: this is just one of them : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jio04YvgraU&t=1862s